# sqlite3 version complications

Tags: python, sqlite

I had recently updated my python version from 3.8.1 to 3.8.2. I had hoped this would also update my sqlite3 from 3.28 to 3.31.1 but to my surprise, it didn't. I was able to make it so that whenever I'd check the version through sqlite3 --version, it'd show up as 3.31.1. But when I check the version through python's interactive, it still shows 3.28. Any solutions?

For system purposes, I'm using macOS Catalina (10.15.4)

Comment: (Windows): Just copy the latest `SQLite3.dll` into `\Python\DLLs` or whatever the paths are on MacOS.

Comment: Although what @tonypdmtr suggests may work and do what you want, you have to realise there's a reason Python is packaged with an older version of SQLite. If Python somehow relies on something that was changed between these versions, you may end up breaking your script and getting very unpredictable and hard to debug issues. It certainly wasn't tested for that. What exactly is the reason you want to upgrade the SQLite version that comes with Python?

Comment: Python uses whatever sqlite version the system it's installed on uses.